# Add places in a KML file to an existing Google Earth project

Tags: google-earth, layer-to-kml

I have a Google Earth project with some placemarks and a KML file with grid boxes. I need to import the boxes in the KML file to the project and add more placemarks to it. I cannot figure out a way to do this. I am working on Google Earth Web.

Edit1: I used the Earth Pro to make a combined .kmz but when I imported it to the earth web it wouldn't let me add placemarks.

Any other apps to do this on the go?

Answer (score 4):

At this time (2021), in Google Earth Web, local KML files and cloud projects are different things and cannot be combined.  I believe the Earth team knows this is an important limitation that needs to be addressed.

For now, one way to combine them is to download a KML from your project with the points, and combine those with the KML of boxes using Earth Pro. Unfortunately you can't yet import the resulting KML back into an Earth Web project (yet?).

Comment: Yes I used the Earth Pro made a combined .kmz but when I imported it to the earth web it wouldn't let me add placemarks. :( any other apps to do this on the go?